Как отладить GRPC API Golang(unknown service grpc postman)
Из Постмена дёргаю:
{
"all": true,
"limit": 1000,
"offset": 0
 }

Выдаёт:

Написал логов везде, где можно было, не проходит:
func NewArticleServiceClient(cc grpc.ClientConnInterface) ArticleServiceClient {
    log.Print("!!retrewt!")
    return &articleServiceClient{cc}
}

func (c *articleServiceClient) GetArticles(ctx context.Context, in *ArticlesRequest, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (*ArticlesResponse, error) {
    log.Print("!!gfhdg!")
    out := new(ArticlesResponse)
    err := c.cc.Invoke(ctx, "/article.ArticleService/GetArticles", in, out, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return out, nil
}

func (c *articleServiceClient) GetArticle(ctx context.Context, in *ArticleRequest, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (*ArticleResponse, error) {
    log.Print("!dsfgdsaf!!")
    out := new(ArticleResponse)
    err := c.cc.Invoke(ctx, "/article.ArticleService/GetArticle", in, out, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return out, nil
}

Пишет анкоун сервис, хотя у меня он есть, порты все проверил.
Подскажите, как вообще отлаживать grpc api,  какая функция дёргается первой и из какого файла. Спасибо

Приведите полный код проекта или основного файла, по примеру gRPC. Для того чтобы делать запросы нужно запускать сервер, который будет слушать на порту и обрабатывать входящие запросы.

@DanielProtopopov Какие расширение имеет основной файл в вашем понимании? Вам нужен сам протокол?
